# nextjs on vercel / zeit writing to disk fs.writeFile

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am using a custom server with nextjs to inject some serverSideProps / getInitialProps into files. What I am doing is having something on the server update a json file every minute or so and then the getServerSideProps/getInitialProps functions read the json file from disk to populate data quickly (without having to do a network request for data).

Everything works great in localhost and when doing a build/running the build locally. In production / after deploying to vercel i get the error: Internal Server Error when trying to open a page. Vercel offers build logs but not any logs for the running custom server.

Is this likely a problem to do with unable to write to disk in the vm's that vercel uses to deploy apps?

Is there an example out there of how I can read/write to disk with a custom server in nextjs for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Vercel is a serverless platform and doesn't support a custom server.

If possible, you can migrate away from the custom server (with API routes) or consider other hosting options.

[Next.js Deployment](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#getting-started)